# Windows Server Scheduled Tasks running command windows, how to prevent them from popping up?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, scheduled-task

On one of my servers we have a lot of scheduled tasks running java programs and what not. The problem is that everytime one of these runs the command window pops up and distracts any work that is being done on the server.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the command windows from popping up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a .bat file in a scheduled task without a window](http://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

splattne explains this very nice here: [Run a .bat file in a scheduled task without a window](https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window).