# How to start scheduled task in minimized cmd window?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, scheduled-task, windows-command-prompt, task-scheduler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a .bat file in a scheduled task without a window](https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window)

In Windows 7, I have a scheduled task running a console application in a CMD window. It runs every day at 12 o'clock. When it runs, it opens a CMD window that is not focused, however, it appears on top of the currently used application.

I would like this CMD window to either start up minimized or run in the background completely (with NO visible windows at all).

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: START /MIN cmd.exe

Comment: OK, so my program/script is right now "foo.exe" and arguments are "-z c". So how/where do I add START /MIN?

Comment: This is the Action dialog, I need to fill out: http://i.imgur.com/ma2qZ.png

Comment: It will still create a console window for the `cmd` process, so this will work if you don't mind a black window flash on screen, otherwise you need another solution. `:-\`